# Multiple Video File uploads using emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to emberjs framework. I have requirement as part of my assignment. I want to create a file upload to add videos.
Multiple video files need to be uploaded. Then need to read the uploaded files using html5 File reader API and then display all the uploaded videos line by line simultaneously.

I don't want to add uploaded videos to any server. Its all client side.

Can any one help me with code snippet for this using emberjs framework.

Thanks
Manohari

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to play the uploaded video without being uploaded on server. to play the uploaded videos you would need to have video url which cannot be created unless you provide the url after you upload thoes videos on server otherwise you can directly use youtube links. so that way we would have address and we can play it.